# How to be sure that either row or column elements are the corresponding eigenvector?

Tags: python

As the question stated how to be sure which either row or column is the corresponding eigenvectors for the eigenvalue?
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
A = [45,37,42,35,39]
B = [38,31,26,28,33]
C = [10,15,17,21,12]
arrays= np.array([A,B,C])
covMatrix = np.cov(arrays,bias=True)
print (covMatrix)
```

Finding eigenvalue and eigenvectors

```
eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(covMatrix)
eigval = eigval.real
print(eigval,"\n", eigvec)
```

The results:

Eigenvalues are:

```
[36.22111819  6.98906964  1.58981217]
```

Eigenvectors are:

```
[[-0.45932764 -0.83268027  0.30929225]
 [-0.63870049  0.55159313  0.53647618]
 [ 0.61731661 -0.04887322  0.78519527]]
```

The question is: In the eigenvalue row, if I just choose, for instance, 1.58981217 eigenvalue element, then which one is the corresponding eigenvectors? Whether is it the third row or the third column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html), referring to the return value `v(…, M, M) array`

> The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]

So that 1.58981217 is the eigenvalue of the vector [0.30929225, 0.53647618, 0.78519527]